# Store Unicoded string into file using python

Tags: python

**temp.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PubmedArticleSet>
    <LastName>Nalivaĭko</LastName>
    <ForeName>Anthony V</ForeName>
</PubmedArticleSet>
```

**MY CODE**

```
import xml.dom.minidom


doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("temp.xml");
file = open('output1.xml','w')

articles = doc.getElementsByTagName('PubmedArticleSet')
for art in articles:
    ln = art.getElementsByTagName("LastName")[0]
    data = ln.firstChild.nodeValue
    file.write("<LastName>")
    file.write(data)
    file.write("</LastName>\n")
print("Completed")
file.close()
```

I need the output as to be the same as the String it is in LastName tag.

**Required Output** - <LastName>Nalivaĭko</LastName>

I'm getting this error while running my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yugam\Desktop\python\ParsingUsingDOM.py", line 12, in <module>
    file.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Yugam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u012d' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the file for writing with the desired encoding like so:

```
open('output1.xml','w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Then you can write out your unicode string as normal.

The output file:

```
<LastName>Nalivaĭko</LastName>
```